# Is there a tool on Unix, Linux, Mac, Windows, Ubuntu, that will list file / directory structure?

Tags: ubuntu, mac, unix, file-management, ls

I wonder if there is a tool that will list file / directory (i.e. take a snapshot of the folder and file structure) like the following:

```
audio
  mp3
    song1.mp3
    some other song.mp3
  audio books
    7 habits.mp3
video
  samples
    up.mov
    cars.mov
```

in other words, in a tree structure.

The Unix command `ls -R` or `ls -lR` can do something similar, except it won't list it indented in a tree structure

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In both Windows and Linux there is a command called tree.

In windows, the `tree` command (or `tree /A /F`) creates something like this:

```
├───plugins
│   ├───dbcopy
│   │   └───util
│   ├───mssql
│   │   └───gui
│   ├───oracle
│   │   └───gui
│   ├───refactoring
│   │   └───gui
│   └───sqlscript
│       └───prefs
└───test
```

In Ubuntu 10.04 you have to install tree with `sudo apt-get install tree`

In linux it looks like this (`tree -a /`)

```
|   |       |-- graphics
|   |       |   `-- fbcon
|   |       |       |-- cursor_blink
|   |       |       |-- power
|   |       |       |   `-- wakeup
|   |       |       |-- rotate
|   |       |       |-- rotate_all
|   |       |       |-- subsystem -> ../../../../class/graphics
|   |       |       `-- uevent
```

These are just small snippets of the tree.

For Mac, you could install the `tree` command following the instructions at [this SuperUser.SE answer](https://superuser.com/a/359727/182034) if you desire the same functionality.

Comment: If you want to save it to a file (at least in Windows), you can use the `/A` switch and redirect to a file (`tree /A /F > tree.txt`), but that only uses ASCII characters. Alternatively, you can use Unicode by redirecting to an RTF file, opening it in Word, and converting from "Encoded Text" with MS-DOS encoding. In that case, the command is `tree /F > tree.rtf`.

Answer (score 2):

For Windows there is `tree /f`

By default, `tree` just displays directories. The `/f` option displays files within each directory as well.

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness: On Mac OS X, this program `tree` is available through fink: `fink install tree`. (Probably available through MacPorts as well.) Of course you can also just download the [source](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/) and compile it yourself.

Comment: Yes - it is available in MacPorts too.